# Buildroot - how to customise an existing kernel defconfig

Tags: kernel, buildroot

I would like to know how to build a custom kernel defconfig (based on the standard `bcmrpi` defconfig as a starting point), using Buildroot's ncurses interfaces.

I currently have `Kernel configuration -> Using an in-tree defconfig file` selected in the Buildroot menuconfig, with `bcmrpi` as the `Defconfig name`.

I have tried making some changes to the kernel with make `linux-menuconfig` but when I try to compile it with `make clean` the changes are not built, and when I check `linux-menuconfig` afterwards they have been reset back to the `bcmrpi` settings.

I would like to be change some settings from these defaults, and then save the resulting settings into a new defconfig, similar to how Buildroot does `make savedefconfig`, but for the kernel. What command do I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buildroot does provide a `make linux-update-defconfig` as explained in the [manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_quick_guide_to_storing_your_project_specific_customizations) - But notice that you need to configure BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE first so it knows where to store the configuration file.

Alternatively you can work with a fragment file, E.G. a snippet of kconfig that gets appended to the bcmrpi_defconfig. See configs/orangepi_zero_defconfig for an example of this.

Comment: Also, if `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE` is set, `make linux-update-defconfig` must be run **before** recompiling the kernel otherwise your configuration changes will be lost

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by making a wrapper script `make-linuxmenuconfig.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash
make linuxmenuconfig
cp output/build/linux-XYZ/.config ../br-external/configs/kernel_config
```

So that my changes are saved automatically after using the configuration editor.
I then added

```
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="../br-external/configs/kernel_config"
```

To the Buildroot configuration.

You might need to change the directories to suit your project layout.

Comment: It's OK, but the script is not needed. Once you point `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE`, launch `make linux-update-defconfig` and Buildroot will update your file, as per @Peter Korsgaard reply.